# Why is my Concurrent call is giving NullPointerException

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

This is my method:

```
private List<OfficerAccountFilter> createResult(List<Account> accountList) {
        List<List<Account>> partedList = Lists.partition(accountList, MAX_LIMIT);
        List<OfficerAccountFilter> result = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("size of account" + accountList.size());
        int size = accountList.size() / 800;
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREDS);
        List<Future<List<OfficerAccountFilter>>> futureList = new ArrayList<Future<List<OfficerAccountFilter>>>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= size + 1; i++) {
            Callable<List<OfficerAccountFilter>> worker = new AccountCallable(accountList);
            Future<List<OfficerAccountFilter>> submit = executorService.submit(worker);
            futureList.add(submit);

        }
        for (Future<List<OfficerAccountFilter>> future : futureList) {
            try {
                result = future.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        return result;
    }
```

my callable class:

```
public class AccountCallable implements Callable<List<OfficerAccountFilter>> {

    @Autowired
    private OfficerAccountSOAPRunner officerAccountSOAPRunner;

    private List<Account> accountList;

    public AccountCallable(List<AccountIdentifier> accountList) {
        this.accountList = accountList;
    }

    @Override
    public List<OfficerAccountFilter> call() throws Exception {

        List<OfficerAccountFilter> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Account account : accountList) {
            OfficerAccountRequest request = new OfficerAccountRequest();
            request.getAccounts().add(account);
            List<OfficerAccountFilter> accounts = officerAccountSOAPRunner.getAccounts(request);
            result.addAll(accounts);
        }
        return result;
    }
}

officerAccountSOAPRunner.getAccounts(request);
```

this is where im invoking Soap service which gives the filtered accounts back to officer. Not sure why is it returning null at this point. If i do it sequentially, it works absolutely fine. Am i not setting the future Object right?

```
Error stack:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at com.test.service.impl.OfficerServiceImpl.createResult(OfficerServiceImpl.java:92)
    at com.test.ServiceImpl.limitOfficerAccounts(OfficerServiceImpl.java:61)
    at com.test.service.impl.OfficerServiceImpl.getOfficerAccounts(OfficerServiceImpl.java:54)


    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.test.impl.AccountIdentifierCallable.call(AccountCallable.java:36)
    at com.test.impl.AccountIdentifierCallable.call(AccountCallable.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
```

The error is SOAPRunner call: `List<OfficerAccountFilter> accounts = officerAccountSOAPRunner.getAccounts(request);`

I put it in debug mode and it's coming as soon as i set on @Autowired. So it's coming from there. Do i need to set the cope differently?

Comment: First, what is the first loop in `createResult` for? You are always passing the complete `accountList` into your callables, so you don't need more than one callable created. Second, which line is throwing the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: The purpose of an exception’s stack trace is that it tells you exactly where the problem occurred.  Please edit your question and include that stack trace.

Comment: i get java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException  on

Comment: The entire stack trace, please.

Answer (score 1):

The `NullPointerException` is because you are autowiring your soap service in your callable:

```
@Autowired
private OfficerAccountSOAPRunner officerAccountSOAPRunner;
```

You are creating the instances of `AccountCallable` yourself and not getting them from Spring, which is correct since you need to create the callables yourself. But Spring cannot then help you with autowiring the soap runner. So you should instead pass in `OfficerAccountSOAPRunner` to your callable as a constructor parameter when your create it's instances in `createResult` method.

You can get the `OfficerAccountSOAPRunner` autowired in the class that contains `createResult` method, so that then it can pass it to the `AccountCallable` objects when it creates them.

On a side note, you don't need to create multiple callables. The following:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= size + 1; i++) {
    Callable<List<OfficerAccountFilter>> worker = new AccountCallable(accountList);
    Future<List<OfficerAccountFilter>> submit = executorService.submit(worker);
    futureList.add(submit);
}
```

can be replaced with:

```
Callable<List<OfficerAccountFilter>> worker = new AccountCallable(accountList);
Future<List<OfficerAccountFilter>> future = executorService.submit(worker);
```

Then you can get the results from the single future:

```
future.get();
```

Comment: Sorry, im setting the accounts, by mnistake i ommitted that line and thanksfor poitning future task out

Comment: @zachandcode In this line: `request.getAccounts().addAll(list);` what is `list`? Did you mean it to be `account`?

Comment: OK, what does your service implementation return if there is no officer account found? Does it return `null` or an empty list? Can you post it's code? The issue seems to be in your service implementation.

Comment: See that's the thing. When i call that service sequentially without executor interface. it works fine. and if the accounts are null, i throw an IllegalArgumentException and it stops right there. Right now,  @Autowired
    private OfficerAccountSOAPRunner officerAccountSOAPRunner; as null when i put it debug mode. But it works fine when i call it in service class. Since im calling it in Callable class, is there any anything i'm missing?

Comment: @zachandcode ah yes, I see now.. @Autowired will not make any difference in your callable, because you are creating the instances of `AccountCallable` yourself. I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Oh, i see. Thanks for pointing that out. Now i have another NPE lol

Comment: NP, where's the NPE now?

Comment: my service internally calls some other service which calls this line. HttpServletRequest servletRequest = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
Need to pass RequestContextHolder in multiple threads. Right now it's passed as single thread.